# Come si esprime il contrario di "a distanza" per qualificare lezioni o lavoro?

Tags: phrase-request, phrase-choice

In spagnolo, il contrario di "*a distancia*" usato per qualificare termini come "lavoro" o "lezioni" si esprime con l'aggettivo "*presencial*" (anche in catalano usiamo questo aggettivo, ma con una pronuncia diversa). Cioè, questo vocabolo si usa per indicare che un lavoro si svolge nel posto di lavoro abituale o che le lezioni si tengono in presenza dell'insegnante. È un aggettivo che in questi giorni si usa molto spesso.

La mia domanda è: come si esprime questa idea in italiano?

Ho l'impressione che si possa dire "di persona", ma non ne sono sicura e non so se esistano altre espressioni per farlo. Una ricerca su Google di "lezioni" e "di persona" sembra confermarlo, ma so per esperienza che le occorrenze che si ottengono in questo modo non sempre sono affidabili.

Alla [voce "persona" del vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/persona/) appare la locuzione "di persona", ma non sembra riportare questo significato.

Ricercando sul *Grande dizionario della lingua italiana* ([[1](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI13/00114.jpg)] e [[2](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI13/00115.jpg)]) ho trovato parecchie espressioni che, per quanto mi è sembrato capire, possono avere questo significato: "con la persona", "personalmente", "di presenza", "in  persona",  "in  prima  persona", "in propria persona", "nella  propria persona", "di persona", "della  persona",  "della  medesima  persona" e
"di  propria  persona".

Comment: Non userei "personalmente" e "della medesima persona" come contrario di "a distanza". Posso usare "personalmente" in frasi come "ho controllato personalmente i messaggi di posta elettronica" che non vuol dire che mi sono recato dove il server della posta elettronica è.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

L'uso più frequente per esprimere il concetto è "in presenza".
Metto [un link a caso](https://www.lastampa.it/politica/2020/07/01/news/scuola-azzolina-mai-detto-didattica-distanza-sostituira-quella-in-presenza-1.39031257) da un quotidiano, ma troverai decine di esempi tra le notizie di questi giorni.

Answer (score 1):

"Sul posto" (e a volte "in loco") sono in certo modo l'esatto contrario di "a distanza".

Non so se sia applicabile al contesto del telelavoro o delle lezioni di un insegnante, ma vi sono diverse frasi dove si usano, per esempio:

"Recarsi sul posto"

"La riparazione sarà fatta in loco"

"Verifichiamo in loco"

"Occorre controllare sul posto"